# Select the first number of a list that is lower than a given number

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

If I have a list such as:

`list={40,40.,40.,40.,40.0001,40.0001,40.0001,40.0002,40.0002,40.0003,40.0003,40.0004,40.0005,40.0005,40.0006,40.0007,40.0008,40.0009,40.001,40.0011,40.0013,40.0014,40.0015,40.0017,40.0018,40.002,40.0021,40.0023,40.0024,40.0026,40.0028,40.003,40.0032,40.0034,40.0036,40.0038,40.004,40.0042,40.0044,40.0047,40.0049,40.0052,40.0054,40.0057,40.0059,40.0062,40.0065,40.0068,40.0071,40.0074,40.0077,40.008,40.0083,40.0086,40.0089,40.0092,40.0096,40.0099,40.0103,40.0106,40.011,40.0113,40.0117,40.0121,40.0125,40.0129,40.0133,40.0137,40.0141,40.0145,40.0149,40.0153,40.0158,40.0162,40.0167,40.0171,40.0176,40.018,40.0185,40.019,40.0194,40.0199,40.0204,40.0209,40.0214,40.0219,40.0224,40.023,40.0235,40.024,40.0246,40.0251,40.0257,40.0262,40.0268,40.0274,40.0279,40.0285,40.0291,40.0297,40.0303,40.0309,40.0315,40.0321,40.0328,40.0334,40.034,40.0347,40.0353,40.036,40.0366,40.0373,40.038,40.0386,40.0393,40.04,40.0407,40.0414,40.0421,40.0428,40.0436,40.0443,40.045,40.0458,40.0465,40.0473,40.048,40.0488,40.0495,40.0503,40.0511,40.0519,40.0527,40.0535,40.0543,40.0551,40.0559,40.0567,40.0575,40.0584,40.0592,40.0601,40.0609,40.0618,40.0626,40.0635,40.0644,40.0653,40.0662,40.0671,40.068,40.0689,40.0698,40.0707,40.0716,40.0725,40.0735,40.0744,40.0754,40.0763,40.0773,40.0782,40.0792,40.0802,40.0812,40.0822,40.0832,40.0842,40.0852,40.0862,40.0872,40.0882,40.0893,40.0903,40.0914,40.0924,40.0935,40.0945,40.0956,40.0967,40.0977,40.0988,40.0999,40.101,40.1021,40.1032,40.1043,40.1055,40.1066,40.1077,40.1089,40.11,40.1112,40.1123,40.1135,40.1147,40.1158,40.117,40.1182,40.1194,40.1206,40.1218,40.123,40.1242,40.1255,40.1267,40.1279,40.1292,40.1304,40.1317,40.1329,40.1342,40.1355,40.1367,40.138,40.1393,40.1406,40.1419,40.1432,40.1445,40.1459,40.1472,40.1485,40.1499,40.1512,40.1526,40.1539,40.1553,40.1566,40.158,40.1594,40.1608,40.1622,40.1636,40.165,40.1664,40.1678,40.1692,40.1706,40.1721,40.1735,40.175,40.1764,40.1779,40.1793,40.1808,40.1823,40.1838,40.1853,40.1868,40.1883,40.1898,40.1913,40.1928,40.1943,40.1958,40.1974,40.1989,40.2005,40.202,40.2036,40.2051,40.2067,40.2083,40.2099,40.2115,40.2131,40.2147,40.2163,40.2179,40.2195,40.2211,40.2228,40.2244,40.2261,40.2277,40.2294,40.231,40.2327,40.2344,40.236,40.2377,40.2394,40.2411,40.2428,40.2445,40.2462,40.248,40.2497,40.2514,40.2532,40.2549,40.2567,40.2584,40.2602,40.262,40.2637,40.2655,40.2673,40.2691,40.2709,40.2727,40.2745,40.2763,40.2782,40.28,40.2818,40.2837,40.2855,40.2874,40.2892,40.2911,40.293,40.2948,40.2967,40.2986,40.3005,40.3024,40.3043,40.3062,40.3082,40.3101,40.312,40.314,40.3159,40.3179,40.3198,40.3218,40.3237,40.3257,40.3277,40.3297,40.3317,40.3337,40.3357,40.3377,40.3397,40.3417,40.3437,40.3458,40.3478,40.3499,40.3519,40.354,40.356,40.3581,40.3602,40.3623,40.3644,40.3664,40.3685,40.3707,40.3728,40.3749,40.377,40.3791,40.3813,40.3834,40.3856,40.3877,40.3899,40.392,40.3942,40.3964,40.3986,40.4008,40.403,40.4052,40.4074,40.4096,40.4118,40.414,40.4163,40.4185,40.4208,40.423,40.4253,40.4275,40.4298,40.4321,40.4343,40.4366,40.4389,40.4412,40.4435,40.4458,40.4481,40.4505,40.4528,40.4551,40.4575,40.4598,40.4622,40.4645,40.4669,40.4693,40.4716,40.474,40.4764,40.4788,40.4812,40.4836,40.486,40.4884,40.4909,40.4933,40.4957,40.4982,40.5006,40.5031,40.5055,40.508,40.5105,40.5129,40.5154,40.5179,40.5204,40.5229,40.5254,40.5279,40.5305,40.533,40.5355,40.5381,40.5406,40.5431,40.5457,40.5483,40.5508,40.5534,40.556,40.5586,40.5612,40.5638,40.5664,40.569,40.5716,40.5742,40.5768,40.5795,40.5821,40.5848,40.5874,40.5901,40.5927,40.5954,40.5981,40.6008,40.6035,40.6062,40.6089,40.6116,40.6143,40.617,40.6197,40.6224,40.6252,40.6279,40.6307,40.6334,40.6362,40.6389,40.6417,40.6445,40.6473,40.6501,40.6529,40.6557,40.6585,40.6613,40.6641,40.6669,40.6698,40.6726,40.6755,40.6783,40.6812,40.684,40.6869,40.6898,40.6926,40.6955,40.6984,40.7013,40.7042,40.7071,40.71,40.713,40.7159,40.7188,40.7218,40.7247,40.7277,40.7306,40.7336,40.7366,40.7395,40.7425,40.7455,40.7485,40.7515,40.7545,40.7575,40.7605,40.7636,40.7666,40.7696,40.7727,40.7757,40.7788,40.7818,40.7849,40.788,40.791,40.7941,40.7972,40.8003,40.8034,40.8065,40.8096,40.8128,40.8159,40.819,40.8222,40.8253,40.8285,40.8316,40.8348,40.8379,40.8411,40.8443,40.8475,40.8507,40.8539,40.8571,40.8603,40.8635,40.8667,40.8699,40.8732,40.8764,40.8797,40.8829,40.8862,40.8894,40.8927,40.896,40.8993,40.9026,40.9059,40.9092,40.9125,40.9158,40.9191,40.9224,40.9257,40.9291,40.9324,40.9358,40.9391,40.9425,40.9458,40.9492,40.9526,40.956,40.9594,40.9628,40.9662,40.9696,40.973,40.9764,40.9798,40.9833,40.9867,40.9902,40.9936,40.9971,41.0005,41.004,41.0075,41.0109,41.0144,41.0179,41.0214,41.0249,41.0284,41.0319,41.0355,41.039,41.0425,41.0461,41.0496,41.0532,41.0567,41.0603,41.0639,41.0674,41.071,41.0746,41.0782,41.0818,41.0854,41.089,41.0926,41.0963,41.0999,41.1035,41.1072,41.1108,41.1145,41.1181,41.1218,41.1255,41.1291,41.1328,41.1365,41.1402,41.1439,41.1476,41.1513,41.1551,41.1588,41.1625,41.1663,41.17,41.1738,41.1775,41.1813,41.185,41.1888,41.1926,41.1964,41.2002,41.204,41.2078,41.2116,41.2154,41.2192,41.223,41.2269,41.2307,41.2346,41.2384,41.2423,41.2461,41.25,41.2539,41.2578,41.2617,41.2656,41.2695,41.2734,41.2773,41.2812,41.2851,41.289,41.293,41.2969,41.3009,41.3048,41.3088,41.3127,41.3167,41.3207,41.3247,41.3287,41.3327,41.3367,41.3407,41.3447,41.3487,41.3527,41.3568,41.3608,41.3649,41.3689,41.373,41.377,41.3811,41.3852,41.3892,41.3933,41.3974,41.4015,41.4056,41.4097,41.4138,41.418,41.4221,41.4262,41.4304,41.4345,41.4387,41.4428,41.447,41.4512,41.4553,41.4595,41.4637,41.4679,41.4721,41.4763,41.4805,41.4847,41.489,41.4932,41.4974,41.5017,41.5059,41.5102,41.5144,41.5187,41.523,41.5272,41.5315,41.5358,41.5401,41.5444,41.5487,41.553,41.5574,41.5617,41.566,41.5704,41.5747,41.579,41.5834,41.5878,41.5921,41.5965,41.6009,41.6053,41.6097,41.6141,41.6185,41.6229,41.6273,41.6317,41.6361,41.6406,41.645,41.6495,41.6539,41.6584,41.6628,41.6673,41.6718,41.6763,41.6808,41.6852,41.6898,41.6943,41.6988,41.7033,41.7078,41.7123,41.7169,41.7214,41.726,41.7305,41.7351,41.7396,41.7442,41.7488,41.7534,41.758,41.7626,41.7672,41.7718,41.7764,41.781,41.7856,41.7903,41.7949,41.7995,41.8042,41.8089,41.8135,41.8182,41.8229,41.8275,41.8322,41.8369,41.8416,41.8463,41.851,41.8557,41.8605,41.8652,41.8699,41.8747,41.8794,41.8842,41.8889,41.8937,41.8985,41.9032,41.908,41.9128,41.9176,41.9224,41.9272,41.932,41.9368,41.9417,41.9465,41.9513,41.9562,41.961,41.9659,41.9707,41.9756,41.9805,41.9853,41.9902,41.9951,42.,42.0049,42.0098,42.0147,42.0197,42.0246,42.0295,42.0345,42.0394,42.0444,42.0493,42.0543,42.0592,42.0642,42.0692,42.0742,42.0792,42.0842,42.0892,42.0942,42.0992,42.1042,42.1092,42.1143,42.1193,42.1244,42.1294,42.1345,42.1395,42.1446,42.1497,42.1548,42.1599,42.1649,42.1701,42.1752,42.1803,42.1854,42.1905,42.1956,42.2008,42.2059,42.2111,42.2162,42.2214,42.2265,42.2317,42.2369,42.2421,42.2473,42.2525,42.2577,42.2629,42.2681,42.2733,42.2785,42.2838,42.289,42.2943,42.2995,42.3048,42.31,42.3153,42.3206,42.3258,42.3311,42.3364,42.3417,42.347,42.3523,42.3576,42.363,42.3683,42.3736,42.379,42.3843,42.3897,42.395,42.4004,42.4058,42.4111,42.4165,42.4219,42.4273,42.4327,42.4381,42.4435,42.4489,42.4544,42.4598,42.4652,42.4707,42.4761,42.4816,42.487,42.4925,42.498,42.5034,42.5089,42.5144,42.5199,42.5254,42.5309,42.5364,42.542,42.5475,42.553,42.5586,42.5641,42.5697,42.5752,42.5808,42.5863,42.5919,42.5975,42.6031,42.6087,42.6143,42.6199,42.6255,42.6311,42.6367,42.6423,42.648,42.6536,42.6593,42.6649,42.6706,42.6762,42.6819,42.6876,42.6933,42.699,42.7047,42.7104,42.7161,42.7218,42.7275,42.7332,42.7389,42.7447,42.7504,42.7562,42.7619,42.7677,42.7734,42.7792,42.785,42.7908,42.7966,42.8024,42.8082,42.814,42.8198,42.8256,42.8314,42.8373,42.8431,42.849,42.8548,42.8607,42.8665,42.8724,42.8783,42.8841,42.89,42.8959,42.9018,42.9077,42.9136,42.9195,42.9255,42.9314,42.9373,42.9433,42.9492,42.9552,42.9611,42.9671,42.9731,42.979,42.985,42.991,42.997,43.003,43.009,43.015,43.021,43.0271,43.0331,43.0391,43.0452,43.0512,43.0573,43.0633,43.0694,43.0755,43.0815,43.0876,43.0937,43.0998,43.1059,43.112,43.1181,43.1243,43.1304,43.1365,43.1427,43.1488,43.155,43.1611,43.1673,43.1734,43.1796,43.1858,43.192,43.1982,43.2044,43.2106,43.2168,43.223,43.2292,43.2354,43.2417,43.2479,43.2542,43.2604,43.2667,43.2729,43.2792,43.2855,43.2918,43.2981,43.3044,43.3107,43.317,43.3233,43.3296,43.3359,43.3422,43.3486,43.3549,43.3613,43.3676,43.374,43.3803,43.3867,43.3931,43.3995,43.4059,43.4123,43.4187,43.4251,43.4315,43.4379,43.4443,43.4508,43.4572,43.4637,43.4701,43.4766,43.483,43.4895,43.496,43.5024,43.5089,43.5154,43.5219,43.5284,43.5349,43.5414,43.548,43.5545,43.561,43.5676,43.5741,43.5807,43.5872,43.5938,43.6004,43.6069,43.6135,43.6201,43.6267,43.6333,43.6399,43.6465,43.6531,43.6598,43.6664,43.673,43.6797,43.6863,43.693,43.6996,43.7063,43.713,43.7196,43.7263,43.733,43.7397,43.7464,43.7531,43.7598,43.7666,43.7733,43.78,43.7868,43.7935,43.8003,43.807,43.8138,43.8205,43.8273,43.8341,43.8409,43.8477,43.8545,43.8613,43.8681,43.8749,43.8817,43.8885,43.8954,43.9022,43.9091,43.9159,43.9228,43.9296,43.9365,43.9434,43.9503,43.9572,43.964,43.9709,43.9779,43.9848,43.9917,43.9986,44.0055,44.0125,44.0194,44.0264,44.0333,44.0403,44.0472,44.0542,44.0612,44.0682,44.0752,44.0822,44.0892,44.0962,44.1032,44.1102,44.1172,44.1243,44.1313,44.1384,44.1454,44.1525,44.1595,44.1666,44.1737,44.1807,44.1878,44.1949,44.202,44.2091,44.2162,44.2233,44.2305,44.2376,44.2447,44.2519,44.259,44.2662,44.2733,44.2805,44.2877,44.2948,44.302,44.3092,44.3164,44.3236,44.3308,44.338,44.3452,44.3525,44.3597,44.3669,44.3742,44.3814,44.3887,44.3959,44.4032,44.4105,44.4177,44.425,44.4323,44.4396,44.4469,44.4542,44.4615,44.4689,44.4762,44.4835,44.4909,44.4982,44.5055,44.5129,44.5203,44.5276,44.535,44.5424,44.5498,44.5572,44.5646,44.572,44.5794,44.5868,44.5942,44.6016,44.6091,44.6165,44.624,44.6314,44.6389,44.6463,44.6538,44.6613,44.6688,44.6763,44.6838,44.6913,44.6988,44.7063,44.7138,44.7213,44.7288,44.7364,44.7439,44.7515,44.759,44.7666,44.7741,44.7817,44.7893,44.7969,44.8045,44.8121,44.8197,44.8273,44.8349,44.8425,44.8501,44.8578,44.8654,44.8731,44.8807,44.8884,44.896,44.9037,44.9114,44.919,44.9267,44.9344,44.9421,44.9498,44.9575,44.9652,44.973,44.9807,44.9884,44.9962,45.0039,45.0117,45.0194,45.0272,45.035,45.0427,45.0505,45.0583,45.0661,45.0739,45.0817,45.0895,45.0973,45.1052,45.113,45.1208,45.1287,45.1365,45.1444,45.1522,45.1601,45.168,45.1758,45.1837,45.1916,45.1995,45.2074,45.2153,45.2232,45.2312,45.2391,45.247,45.255,45.2629,45.2709,45.2788,45.2868,45.2947,45.3027,45.3107,45.3187,45.3267,45.3347,45.3427,45.3507,45.3587,45.3667,45.3747,45.3828,45.3908,45.3989,45.4069,45.415,45.423,45.4311,45.4392,45.4473,45.4554,45.4635,45.4716,45.4797,45.4878,45.4959,45.504,45.5121,45.5203,45.5284,45.5366,45.5447,45.5529,45.561,45.5692,45.5774,45.5856,45.5938,45.602,45.6102,45.6184,45.6266,45.6348,45.643,45.6513,45.6595,45.6678,45.676,45.6843,45.6925,45.7008,45.7091,45.7173,45.7256,45.7339,45.7422,45.7505,45.7588,45.7671,45.7755,45.7838,45.7921,45.8005,45.8088,45.8172,45.8255,45.8339,45.8423,45.8506,45.859,45.8674,45.8758,45.8842,45.8926,45.901,45.9094,45.9179,45.9263,45.9347,45.9432,45.9516,45.9601,45.9685,45.977,45.9855,45.9939,46.0024,46.0109,46.0194,46.0279,46.0364,46.0449,46.0535,46.062,46.0705,46.0791,46.0876,46.0962,46.1047,46.1133,46.1218,46.1304,46.139,46.1476,46.1562,46.1648,46.1734,46.182,46.1906,46.1992,46.2078,46.2165,46.2251,46.2338,46.2424,46.2511,46.2597,46.2684,46.2771,46.2858,46.2945,46.3032,46.3118,46.3206,46.3293,46.338,46.3467,46.3554,46.3642,46.3729,46.3817,46.3904,46.3992,46.4079,46.4167,46.4255,46.4343,46.4431,46.4519,46.4607,46.4695,46.4783,46.4871,46.4959,46.5048,46.5136,46.5224,46.5313,46.5402,46.549,46.5579,46.5668,46.5756,46.5845,46.5934,46.6023,46.6112,46.6201,46.629,46.638,46.6469,46.6558,46.6648,46.6737,46.6827,46.6916,46.7006,46.7096,46.7185,46.7275,46.7365,46.7455,46.7545,46.7635,46.7725,46.7815,46.7906,46.7996,46.8086,46.8177,46.8267,46.8358,46.8448,46.8539,46.863,46.872,46.8811,46.8902,46.8993,46.9084,46.9175,46.9266,46.9358,46.9449,46.954,46.9632,46.9723,46.9814,46.9906,46.9998,47.0089,47.0181,47.0273,47.0365,47.0457,47.0549,47.0641,47.0733,47.0825,47.0917,47.1009,47.1102,47.1194,47.1287,47.1379,47.1472,47.1564,47.1657,47.175,47.1843,47.1936,47.2028,47.2121,47.2215,47.2308,47.2401,47.2494,47.2587,47.2681,47.2774,47.2868,47.2961,47.3055,47.3148,47.3242,47.3336,47.343,47.3524,47.3618,47.3712,47.3806,47.39,47.3994,47.4088,47.4183,47.4277,47.4371,47.4466,47.4561,47.4655,47.475,47.4845,47.4939,47.5034,47.5129,47.5224,47.5319,47.5414,47.5509,47.5605,47.57,47.5795,47.5891,47.5986,47.6082,47.6177,47.6273,47.6369,47.6464,47.656,47.6656,47.6752,47.6848,47.6944,47.704,47.7136,47.7233,47.7329,47.7425,47.7522,47.7618,47.7715,47.7811,47.7908,47.8005,47.8101,47.8198,47.8295,47.8392,47.8489,47.8586,47.8683,47.8781,47.8878,47.8975,47.9073,47.917,47.9267,47.9365,47.9463,47.956,47.9658,47.9756,47.9854,47.9952,48.005,48.0148,48.0246,48.0344,48.0442,48.054,48.0639,48.0737,48.0836,48.0934,48.1033,48.1131,48.123,48.1329,48.1428,48.1527,48.1625,48.1724,48.1824,48.1923,48.2022,48.2121,48.222,48.232,48.2419,48.2519,48.2618,48.2718,48.2817,48.2917,48.3017,48.3117,48.3217,48.3317,48.3417,48.3517,48.3617,48.3717,48.3817,48.3918,48.4018,48.4119,48.4219,48.432,48.442,48.4521,48.4622,48.4722,48.4823,48.4924,48.5025,48.5126,48.5227,48.5328,48.543,48.5531,48.5632,48.5734,48.5835,48.5937,48.6038,48.614,48.6242,48.6343,48.6445,48.6547,48.6649,48.6751,48.6853,48.6955,48.7057,48.716,48.7262,48.7364,48.7467,48.7569,48.7672,48.7774,48.7877,48.798,48.8082,48.8185,48.8288,48.8391,48.8494,48.8597,48.87,48.8804,48.8907,48.901,48.9114,48.9217,48.9321,48.9424,48.9528,48.9631,48.9735,48.9839,48.9943,49.0047,49.0151,49.0255,49.0359,49.0463,49.0567,49.0671,49.0776,49.088,49.0985,49.1089,49.1194,49.1298,49.1403,49.1508,49.1613,49.1718,49.1823,49.1928,49.2033,49.2138,49.2243,49.2348,49.2453,49.2559,49.2664,49.277,49.2875,49.2981,49.3086,49.3192,49.3298,49.3404,49.351,49.3616,49.3722,49.3828,49.3934,49.404,49.4146,49.4253,49.4359,49.4466,49.4572,49.4679,49.4785,49.4892,49.4999,49.5105,49.5212,49.5319,49.5426,49.5533,49.564,49.5747,49.5855,49.5962,49.6069,49.6177,49.6284,49.6392,49.6499,49.6607,49.6715,49.6822,49.693,49.7038,49.7146,49.7254,49.7362,49.747,49.7578,49.7687,49.7795,49.7903,49.8012,49.812,49.8229,49.8337,49.8446,49.8555,49.8663,49.8772,49.8881,49.899,49.9099,49.9208,49.9317,49.9427,49.9536,49.9645,49.9755,49.9864,49.9974,50.0083,50.0193,50.0302,50.0412,50.0522,50.0632,50.0742,50.0852,50.0962,50.1072,50.1182,50.1292,50.1402,50.1513,50.1623,50.1734,50.1844,50.1955,50.2065,50.2176,50.2287,50.2398,50.2509,50.262,50.2731,50.2842,50.2953,50.3064,50.3175,50.3286,50.3398,50.3509,50.3621,50.3732,50.3844,50.3955,50.4067,50.4179,50.4291,50.4403,50.4515,50.4627,50.4739,50.4851,50.4963,50.5075,50.5188,50.53,50.5413,50.5525,50.5638,50.575,50.5863,50.5976,50.6088,50.6201,50.6314,50.6427,50.654,50.6653,50.6766,50.688,50.6993,50.7106,50.722,50.7333,50.7447,50.756,50.7674,50.7788,50.7901,50.8015,50.8129,50.8243,50.8357,50.8471,50.8585,50.8699,50.8814,50.8928,50.9042,50.9157,50.9271,50.9386,50.95,50.9615,50.973,50.9844,50.9959,51.0074,51.0189,51.0304,51.0419,51.0534,51.065,51.0765,51.088,51.0996,51.1111,51.1227,51.1342,51.1458,51.1573,51.1689,51.1805,51.1921,51.2037,51.2153,51.2269,51.2385,51.2501,51.2617,51.2733,51.285,51.2966,51.3083,51.3199,51.3316,51.3432,51.3549}`

How can I find the first value of the list that is immediately below and closest to 50 (in this case it would be `49.9974`?. I tried using `closest = SelectFirst[list, # < 50 &]` but it seems this does not work with list with numbers in ascending order. I do not want to use Nearest[list, 50] because I also have other list where the closest number to 50 may be the a higher number than 50 (e.g. 50.0001) and I am only interested in the closest number to 50 that is immediately lower than 50 in a list of ascending order.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not `Max[Select[list, # < 50 &]]`?

Comment: @J.M. The reason I do not use that is because let's say I have {....49.99999,50,50.0001.....etc} then it will give me `50` rather than `49.99999`. Is there any way to exclude the 50 as well as to have the number immediately below and closest to 50?

Comment: @John - if you look at the InputForm or FullForm of the result you will see that the `50.` is actually `49.99999`. Your "Number of digits displayed in output" is set to `6` and `49.99999` displays as `50.`

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you for the clarification! Then the code works!

Comment: @John if you had clarified further your question I answered previously, then you could have avoided this question being necessary (this was one part of what I had asked about in your needs for use). That said I will update the code to make this possible and post it here as an answer. :) it’s a combo (in my mind) of `Select`, `Ordering`, or `Sort`.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so, let's see why `SelectFirst` worked for the greater-than case, and why `Max` is a better option for the less-than case, especially if we have an unordered `list` as our input:

```
lthan = Select[list, # < 50 &];
gthan = Select[list, # > 50 &];
#@lthan & /@ {Max, First, Last}
#@gthan & /@ {Min, First, Last}

(* {49.9974, 40, 49.9974} *)
(* {50.0083, 50.0083, 51.3549} *)
```

However, the above may not be explanative enough, so, if we wanted to use `SelectFirst` the `list` should be ordered in such a way as to allow for this. In your previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221950/which-condition-inside-a-loop-with-unknown-value-in-a-condition), it was strictly descending, and so we can see the same thing here:

```
SelectFirst[Reverse@list, # < 50 &]

(* 49.9974 *)
```

And, the following might be interesting or useful to you:

```
MinMax /@ GatherBy[list, # < 50 &]

(* {{40, 49.9974}, {50.0083, 51.3549}} *)
```

Finally, using something like `Position`, `Sort`, or `Ordering`, we could also make an attempt at this procedure for an unordered `list`...but that is outside of the scope of this QA.